# Получить процент группы из df.groupby() по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Вопрос: Люди моложе 30 лет выживали чаще, чем люди старше 60 лет? Каковы доли выживших в обеих группах?

Ответ:
40.6% среди молодых и 22.7% среди старых

```
Age_category    1   2   3
Survived            
           0    228 17  304
           1    156 5   181
```

Сгруппировал людей по возрастному признаку:
    def age_category(age):
        if age < 30:
            return 1
        elif age > 60:
            return 2
        else:
            return 3
А далее хочу узнать процент выживших людей тех кому менее 30 и аналогично для людей старше 60 лет.

```
df2 = data.groupby(['Survived', 
'Age_category']).size()  / 
df3.sort_values('vol').groupby(level=0).tail(1) * 100
df2
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться тем фактом, что невыжившие в столбце `Survived` обозначаются нулем:

```
In [292]: data.groupby(pd.cut(data.Age, [0, 30, 61, 130], right=False))['Survived'].mean().mul(100)
Out[292]:
Age
[0, 30)      40.625000
[30, 61)     41.883117
[61, 130)    22.727273
Name: Survived, dtype: float64
```

или так:

```
In [293]: data.groupby(pd.cut(data.Age, [0, 29, 60, 130]))['Survived'].mean().mul(100)
Out[293]:
Age
(0, 29]      40.625000
(29, 60]     41.883117
(60, 130]    22.727273
Name: Survived, dtype: float64
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [319]: bins = [0, 29, 60, np.inf]

In [320]: labels = ['young','adult','older']

In [321]: res = (data.groupby(pd.cut(data.Age, bins=bins, labels=labels))
                     ['Survived']
                     .mean()
                     .mul(100))

In [322]: res
Out[322]:
Age
young    40.625000
adult    41.883117
older    22.727273
Name: Survived, dtype: float64

In [323]: res.loc['young']
Out[323]: 40.625

In [324]: res.loc['older']
Out[324]: 22.727272727272727
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Но хотелось бы уточнить каким образом я могу вытащить нужное значение полученное с использованием метода .groupby ?

Comment: И второй вопрос вот диапазон выбран до 130 а если я не знаю лимита? Ну т.е. табличное значение к примеру динамичное. Сегодня одни данные завтра в них будут добавлены 270 к примеру.

Comment: что значит вытащить полученное значение? можете привести пример?

Comment: @HelloGoogle, я взял 130 из соображений здравого смысла (люди больше не живут). Для произвольной задачи лучше брать бесконечность (`np.inf`)

Comment: Спасибо :) Вы мне очень помогли)

Comment: @HelloGoogle, всегда рад помочь :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
round(data["Survived"][(data['Age']>60)].mean(),4)*100
round(data["Survived"][(data['Age']<30)].mean(),4)*100
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]